# Get data from an object that is sometimes null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The site has a window (done with `Dialog mui`) that opens to get information (Device with id {} is at the user's) .
There is a static text in this window (which is always present) and I want to finish off the text (in my case ID), which will change depending on the data.

My data is stored in the `selectedItem` object. But here the problem is, when the window (`Dialog mui`) is closed, then `selectedItem === null`.

Please tell me how to get ID correctly

```
export default function Table() {
  const records = useRecords(firestore)
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();

  const handleClose = () => {
      setSelectedItem(null);
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={!!selectedItem} onClose={handleClose}>
        Device with id {} is at the user's
      </Dialog>

      {records.map((record) =>
        <TableCell record={record} 
                          onDeleteButtonPress={() => setSelectedItem(record)} 
                          key={record.id} />)}
          
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you getting an error? Eg: _"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')"_

Comment: @Nick Parsons Yes, exactly this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use another state to open/close that dialog accordingly. You can check the below code with my comments.

```
export default function Table() {
  const records = useRecords(firestore)
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();
  //the new dialog state
  const [isDialogOpened, setIsDialogOpened] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
      //close the dialog manually with a state update
      setIsDialogOpened(false);
  }

  //when `selectedItem` is true, we will open the dialog
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(selectedItem) {
       setIsDialogOpened(true)
    }
  }, [selectedItem])
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={isDialogOpened} onClose={handleClose}>
        Device with id {} is at the user's
      </Dialog>

      {records.map((record) =>
        <TableCell record={record} 
                          onDeleteButtonPress={() => setSelectedItem(record)} 
                          key={record.id} />)}
          
    </div>
  )
}
```

---

If you don't want to have side-effects from `useEffect`, you can update `isDialogOpened` state in `onDeleteButtonPress` event as well.

```
export default function Table() {
  const records = useRecords(firestore)
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();
  //the new dialog state
  const [isDialogOpened, setIsDialogOpened] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => {
      //close the dialog manually with a state update
      setIsDialogOpened(false);
  }
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={isDialogOpened} onClose={handleClose}>
        Device with id {} is at the user's
      </Dialog>

      {records.map((record) =>
        <TableCell record={record} 
                          onDeleteButtonPress={() => {
         setSelectedItem(record);
         setIsDialogOpened(true); //open the dialog in `onDeleteButtonPress`
}} 
                          key={record.id} />)}
          
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I'm looking for, thanks. But there is one caveat: When I open the Dialog and then close it everything works fine. But if I open it again, it no longer works (does not open). Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: I give the 2nd solution that will update `isDialogOpened` state directly under `onDeleteButtonPress`. Hopefully, it can help you in that case :D @Paul

Comment: Better to keep side effects in  handlers than useEffect anyway. [You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Comment: @Nick Vu Thanks for the help! I understood the logic of your solution and this is the most suitable option for me

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid trying to read `id` when `selectedItem` is `undefined`/`null`:

```js
<Dialog open={!!selectedItem} onClose={handleClose}>
  Device with id {selectedItem?.id} is at the user's
</Dialog>
```

The problem is that React still evaluates its children even if the component they sit within (in this case `Dialog`) doesn't get rendered. That's because the above JSX code [transpiles](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) into the following `React.createElement()` function call:

```js
React.createElement(Dialog, {
  open: !!selectedItem,
  onClose: handleClose
}, "Device with id ", selectedItem?.id, " is at the user's");
```

So each of the arguments need to be evaluated before `createElement()` is called, meaning that if you were to use `selectedItem.id` when `selectedItem` is `null`/`undefined`, JS would throw an error when this is evaluated. With optional chaining however, when `selectedItem?.id` is evaluated we get back `undefined` instead of JS throwing an error.

Comment: Yes, this solution suits me very well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be setting it to null on close? Just remove the

```
setSelectedItem(null)
```

from the handle close. This should keep the state after closing the dialog.

Comment: Yes, but then I won't be able to close this window

Comment: Then I would recommend using another state variable like following. `const [dialog,setDialog] = useState(false);` . Then in the handleClose `setDialog(false); ` again. It will work the same essentially. The only difference is that your record state will stay the same once the dialog closes. Review @Nick Vu post above.